# There exists a positive integer $s$ for which the number of divisors of $sn$ and of $sk$ are equal.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

IMO 2018 SL N1: Determine all pairs $(n, k)$ of distinct positive integers such that there exists a positive integer $s$ for which the number of divisors of $sn$ and of $sk$ are equal.

I am stuck. Here is my progress.

If $k|n$ then it is not possible.

Let $k={p_1}^{\alpha_1}\cdot{p_2}^{\alpha_2}\dots \cdots {p_m}^{\alpha_m}. $

Let $n={p_1}^{\beta_1}\cdot{p_2}^{\beta_2}\dots \cdots {p_m}^{\beta_m}. $

Where $\alpha_i, \beta_i\ge 0.$

Then the number of divisors of $k$ is $ (\alpha_1+1)\dots(\alpha_m+1)$ and of $n$ is $(\beta_1+1)\dots(\beta_m+1).$

Now there will be a exponent $\alpha_i$ such that $\alpha_i>\beta_i.$ If not then $k|n.$ Say WLOG $\alpha_1>\beta_1.$

Similarly there will be a exponent $\alpha_i$ such that $\alpha_i<\beta_i.$ If not then $m|n.$ Say WLOG $\alpha_2<\beta_2.$

Now we can probably let $S=p_1^a\cdot p_2^b.$

We want $(\alpha_3+1)\dots(\alpha_m+1)(a+\alpha_1+1)(b+\alpha_2+1)=(\beta_3+1)\dots(\beta_m+1)(a+\beta_1+1)(b+\beta_2+1).$

We can treat $(\alpha_3+1)\dots(\alpha_m+1)=Y$ as a constant and $(\beta_3+1)\dots(\beta_m+1)=Z$ as constant.

I am not sure on how to proceed. We just have to construct those $a,b.$

Comment: Where did $m$ come from?

Comment: It seems to me that if $\displaystyle n = \prod_{i=1}^r (p_i)^{\alpha_i}$ and $\displaystyle k = \prod_{i=1}^t (q_i)^{\beta_i}$ where $p_1,\cdots,p_r, q_1, \cdots q_t$ are prime numbers, and if $\displaystyle T_n = \prod_{i=1}^r (\alpha_i + 1) = T_k = \prod_{i=1}^t (\beta_i + 1)$ then $n,k$ are automatically a satisfactory pair.  So, the question is, under what circumstances can $n,k$ be a satisfactory pair, even though $T_n \neq T_k$?

Comment: @user10354138 My *guess* is that the OP used $m$ when he meant to use $k$.  However, I could be wrong.

Comment: @user10354138 this problem has two different statements i.e one uses  n, k other uses n,m.

Comment: To the OP: for what it's worth, you seem to be assuming that the two different numbers, $n$ and $k$, use the same prime numbers in their prime factorization.  I see no reason that this would necessarily be true, since the only issue is the number of divisors of $sn$ and $sk$.

Comment: @user2661923 note that he wrote that exponents can be 0

Comment: I remember this, this was one of the questions from the 2019 IMO selection exams in Germany, there is a solution [here](https://www.mathe-wettbewerbe.de/fileadmin/Mathe-Wettbewerbe/AIMO/Aufgaben_und_Loesungen_AIMO/loes_awkl_19.pdf) (in German).

Comment: @user2661923 what do you mean by if $T_n=T_k$ then $n,k$ are automatically a satisfactory pair?can you elaborate?

Comment: @user69608 Suppose that $\displaystyle n = \prod_{i=1}^r (p_i)^{\alpha_i},   k = \prod_{i=1}^t (q_i)^{\beta_i}$.  Here, I intend that $S_1 = \{p_1, \cdots, p_r\}$ are all distinct primes, as are $S_2 = \{q_1, \cdots, q_t\}$, while $S_1$ and $S_2$ may or may not intersect.  Choose any prime $a$ that is not in $S_1 \cup S_2$, and choose any positive  integer exponent $b$, so that $s = a^b$.  Then  the number of factors of $s\times n$ will be the number of factors of $n \times (b+1)$.  Ditto for the factors of $s \times k$.  ...see next comment

Comment: @user69608 This means that if $n,k$ have the same # of factors, you can always find an $s$ such that $(s \times n)$ has the same # of factors as $(s \times k).$

Comment: @user2661923 thanks ,got it. From your first comment, wasn't our main goal to find $n,k$ such that $T_n=T_k$ ?If for a case $T_n \neq T_k$,How would $n,k$ which are satisfactory pair contribute to answer because we wanted $T_n = T_k$?

Comment: @user69608 No, finding $n,k$ such that $T_n = T_k$ is fairly easy, although identifying all possible pairs $(n,k) ~: ~T_n = T_k$ may be significantly more difficult, because the number of distinct primes that show in the prime factorization of $n$ (equal to $r$ in my example) don't necessarily have to equal the number of distinct primes that show in the prime factorization of $k$ (equal to $t$ in my example).  ...see next comment

Comment: @user69608 As I see it, the real challenge is to identify all pairs $(n,k)$ where $T_n \neq T_k$ and yet despite this, a scalar $s$ can be constructed so that the number of factors of $(s \times n)$ equals the number of factors of $(s \times k)$.  As an example of where this is plausible, suppose that $T_n = (8/9) \times T_k$.  If there exists a prime number $a$ such that $a^1$ is in the prime factorization of $n$ and $a^2$ is in the prime factorization of $k$ then you can set $s = a$.  ...see next comment

Comment: @user69608 Then, the number of factors of $(s\times n)$ will be $(3/2) \times T_n$, while the number of factors of $(s \times k)$ will be $(4/3) \times T_k$.  Note that $(3/2) \times (8/9) = (4/3).$

Comment: @user2661923 got it. thanks for explaining.any hints for how to find satisfactory $n,k$ pair? I haven't seen calvin's sol yet. condition $T_n=T_k$ for $n,k$ is a subset of superset of satisfactory $n,k$ right?like how would we define for a given $n,k$ to be satisfactory.

Comment: @user69608 The whole topic is very challenging.  I am going to leave it to someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, however:

Looking at your $ S = p_1 ^a \times p_2 ^b$ hypothesis, we want to solve the general equation:

$$(a + \alpha_1 + 1)(b+\alpha_2 + 1 ) Y = (a+\beta_1 + 1 ) ( b+ \beta_2 + 1 ) Z.$$

For $\alpha_1 > \beta_1$, we have $ 1 < \frac{ a +\alpha_1 + 1 } { a + \beta_1 + 1 } \leq \frac{ \alpha_1 + 1 }{\beta_1 + 1 }.$
For $ \alpha_2 < \beta_2$, we have $ \frac{\alpha_2 + 1 } { \beta_2 + 1 } \leq \frac{ b +\alpha_2 + 1 } { b + \beta_2 + 1 } < 1 $.
So, if a solution exists, we require $  \frac{\alpha_2 + 1 } { \beta_2 + 1 } < \frac{Z}{Y} <  \frac{ \alpha_1 + 1 }{\beta_1 + 1 }$.
There are clearly counter examples to this constraint, thus the simplistic $ S = p_1 ^a \times p_2 ^b$ isn't sufficient.
In particular, this argument strongly suggests that we want to bound the "leftover term $\frac{Z}{Y}$" very closely to 1, which happens when all of the prime factors are involved.

---

If you haven't already done this, I strongly suggest showing that an $s$ exists for the small cases $ (n,k) = (2, 3), (4, 3), (12, 18), (6,5), (30, 7), (30, 77)$.
It is from working with these cases that I found the following solution.

---

There are 3 types of primes to consider:

1. Set A: Those that appear more often in $n$ than in $k$.
2. Set B: Those that appear more often in $k$ than in $n$.
3. Set C: Those that appear equal often in $k$ and $n$. -> These do not matter. We can ignore them (EG Primes that occur in neither).

As you realized, a necessary condition is $ n \not \mid k, k \not \mid n$.
This means that sets $A$, $B$ are non-empty, which is crucial.
As it turns out, the necessary condition is also a sufficient condition (to be shown).

**Claim:** There exists a $D$ such that for any $d \geq D$, we can find integers $\alpha_i$ such that

$$ \prod_{p_i \in A} \frac{ v_{p_i} (n) + \alpha_i + 1 } { v_{p_i} (k) + \alpha_i + 1 } = \frac{d+1}{d}. $$

Likewise, there exists a $E$ such that for any $ e \geq E$, we can find integers $\beta_j$ such that

$$ \prod_{q_j \in B} \frac{ v_{q_j} (k) + \beta_j + 1 } { v_{q_j} (n) + \beta_j + 1 } = \frac{e+1}{e}. $$

**Corollary:** Take $d= e =  \max(D, E)$ and the corresponding integers.
Then for $s = \prod p_i ^ {\alpha_i} \times \prod q_j^{\beta_j}$, we get that $\sigma(sn) = \sigma(sk)$.
So the condition $ n\not\mid k, k\not\mid n$ is sufficient.

**Proof of claim:** Try this for yourself. If you're stuck, state what you've tried.
As a cryptic hint, set up a another claim in a similar manner to the claim.